# Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetchcontent' while exporting action in Reduxer

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to export an extraReducer with Redux Toolkit but I got a problem also if you do see other errors in the code tell me, here is the code below and the error I'm getting:

`Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'fetchcontent'.`

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const fetchContent = createAsyncThunk('random', async (view, language) => {
  fetch(`https://myhiddensite.com/${view}/${language}/random`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) =>  return data;);
});

export const contentSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'content',
  initialState: { value: null },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchContent.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { fetchContent } = contentSlice.actions;
export default contentSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [createSlice#return-value](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#return-value) doc:

> Each function defined in the `reducers` argument will have a corresponding action creator generated using `createAction` and included in the result's actions field using the same function name.

You didn't define any function in the `reducers`, so there is no action creator generated and included in the `contentSlice.actions` field.

You can export the thinks:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const fetchContent = createAsyncThunk('random', async (view, language) => {
  return fetch(`https://myhiddensite.com/${view}/${language}/random`)
    .then((response) => response.json());
});

export const contentSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'content',
  initialState: { value: null },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [fetchContent.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const thunks = {
  fetchContent,
};
export default contentSlice.reducer;
```